# What does Tkinter END do?

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-text

I was wondering what the exact purpose of Tkinter END is, when it's used before or after a string of text. The text is not displayed when I remove END, but what is it exactly for?

Comment: `tkinter.END` is a constant that refers to the string `'end'`. You might need to explain your problem with a code

Answer (score 2):

> What does Tkinter END do?

`END` doesn't do anything. It's just a constant, containing the string "end". In the context of a text widget it is a special index that represents the point immediately after the last character.

Personally, I never use it. Using the actual string `"end"` works just as well.